# Should I approve suggested edits on EOL questions?

Tags: discussion

I've came across [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505795/problem-after-editing-rc-local-in-ubuntu) which is about 13.04, I flagged it EOL. A few minutes later I met [this suggested edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/301078). It's a minor spelling edit.

What do you do in these situations? Do you approve or reject edits on questions that you know will be closed (in this case, because it's EOL)?

*EDIT*: in this specific case, the edit was rejected because it's too minor. But my question still stands in general.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, yes, you should approve/improve a suggested edit on EOL questions, or "questions that you know will be closed", but I wouldn't really put much effort like you did in that suggested edit you linked.

On a very broad perspective, I see editing a question as making it:

1. Easier to read. This is done by correcting spelling mistakes. And,
2. Easier to search for. This is done by correcting major mistakes like a wrong file being mentioned, or a wrong tag on the question.

**Easier to read** edits on questions that are closed/you know will be closed doesn't do much good, because it's eventually going to be closed. An example of this is the suggested edit you linked. As I mentioned, *I* would've done something else rather than correct those spelling mistakes on a question that will be closed. But to answer your umbrella question, yes, if an edit makes it *easier to read*, I would have approved the suggested edit.

**Easier to search for** edits are important because the whole point of AskUbuntu is to make it easier for users to search for old questions, so editing a closed/going to be closed question to correct a mistake should definitely be approved. People need to be able to find those closed questions.